# Intercepting a Controller - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want to intercept ALL Controller actions and do one of two things (depending on an option - for this example say a query string value in the URL):

(1) Return an array of just the variables instead of rendering the template

(2) Render the template exactly, but ignore any 'extends' actions inside that template

The reason for this is that using the same server-side code, option 1 allows me to just return variables for say an Ajax request, and option 2 allows me to just return the content part of the HTML (for Ajax) rather than the full HTML with navigation etc.

I've tried extending a controller, but kept getting that annoying 'doesn't match up with Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller' problem.

I've tried using an event listener, which seems to have gotten me closer, but I don't think listening to a controller event actually runs the controller.

I'm sure this should be easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FOSRestBundle or just its parts for this purpose.

From README.md:

> A View layer to enable output and format agnostic Controllers

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle

Comment: Thanks. Is that the best way as it seems overkill for my simple requirement? I thought I could just extend a controller, or something very small.

Comment: =), maybe it's overkill. Of course, you can write listeners, but if you have no time, just use FOSRestBundle.